# Wordpress/Woocommerce Admin Order City dropdown based on state

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a city dropdown in my Woocommerce store's admin order edit area. I have tried this code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'admin_billing_city_select_field' );
function admin_billing_city_select_field( $fields ) {
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Only for new order creation
    if( $pagenow != 'post-new.php' ) return $fields;

    $fields['city'] = array(
        'label'   => __( 'City', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show'    => false,
        'class'   => 'js_field-city select short',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            ''              => __( 'Select a city&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ),
            'Los Angeles'   => __( 'Los Angeles', 'woocommerce' ),
            'San Antonio'   => __( 'San Antonio', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

It's working like this

[image]

But I want to add some condition If the state matches then it will show a specific city list. And it should revel the city list after selecting the state. How can I do this?

**Edit 1**

I have added places as an array. And here is the full code in [Github](https://github.com/mdfathi99/Cities-Dropdown-for-WooCommerce-Add-New-Order).

```
global $places;
$places['BD'] = array(
    'dhaka' => array(
        __('Aam Bagan', 'woocommerce'),
        __('12 Tala', 'woocommerce'),
        __('Keraniganj Upazila Sadar', 'woocommerce'),
    ),
    'faridpur' => array(
        __('Alfadanga', 'woocommerce'),
    ),
    'gazipur' => array(
        __('Gazipur Sadar', 'woocommerce'),
        __('Kaliakair', 'woocommerce'),
    ),
    'gopalganj' => array(
        __('Gopalganj Sadar', 'woocommerce'),
        __('Kashiani', 'woocommerce'),
    ),
    'jamalpur' => array(
        __('Bakshiganj', 'woocommerce'),
        __('Dewanganj', 'woocommerce'),
    ),
);

function enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.0.13', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('place-select-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/place-select.js', array('jquery', 'select2'), '0.1', true);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');


add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'admin_billing_city_select_field');
function admin_billing_city_select_field($fields)
{
    global $pagenow, $places;

    // Only for new order creation
    if ($pagenow != 'post-new.php') return $fields;

    $options = array('' => __('Select a city&hellip;', 'woocommerce'));
    if (isset($places)) {
        foreach ($places as $state => $cities) {
            foreach ($cities as $city => $city_name) {
                $options[$city] = $city_name[0];
            }
        }
    }

    $fields['city'] = array(
        'label'   => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
        'show'    => false,
        'class'   => 'js_field-city select short',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'options' => $options,
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

The imported jquery file is from @Aurelien - AK Digital's answer. But it's returning only the first item of the array.
[image]

If I change `$options[$city] = $city_name[0];` to `$options[$city] = $city_name;` it's returning a string text instead of cities `"Array"` How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First, for a better user experience, I recommend to move the "State field" before the "City" & "Postcode" fields.

You also may have to think about the amount of data you'll want to load. Will you propose every single US city and town or only a few ? This will conditionned the way data will be load.

But let's assume you will create you're own [short] list.

***(All of this code has been tested WP 6.1.1 & WC 7.3.0)***

1. First you need to store that list of cities, including state prefixes, in a WordPress option (ex.: `'_wc_cities_by_states'`) like so :

```
$state_city_options = array(
        'CA-los-angeles' => __( 'Los Angeles', 'woocommerce' ),
        'CA-san-antonio' => __( 'San Antonio', 'woocommerce' ),
        'WA-seattle'     => __( 'Seattle', 'woocommerce' ),
        'WA-olympia'     => __( 'Olympia', 'woocommerce' ),
    ); 

set_option('_wc_cities_by_states', $state_city_options);
```

2. Then, get this custom option to build your city select option list :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'admin_billing_city_select_field' );
function admin_billing_city_select_field( $fields ) {
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Get the array of cities by state from WP option
    $cities_by_states = get_option('_wc_cities_by_states', )

    // Only for new order creation
    if( $pagenow != 'post-new.php' || !$cities_by_states ) return $fields;

    // Add it to WC city fields
    $fields['city'] = array(
        'label'   => __( 'City', 'woocommerce' ),
        'show'    => false,
        'class'   => 'js_field-city select short',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'options' => $cities_by_states;
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

3. Finally, this is the Javascript (jQuery) that will do the trick (NB: Woocommerce use the select2 lib) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".js_field-city option").hide();

  //Required to biding after billing-edit click
  $(".edit_address").one("click", function () {
    filterCities();
  });

  //Required to avoid unbiding after Country change
  $(".js_field-country").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    filterCities();
  });

  filterCities = () => {
    $(".js_field-state").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
      var state = $(this).select2("data")[0].id;
      $(".js_field-city option").hide();
      $(".js_field-city option[value^='" + state + "']").show();
      $(".js_field-city").val(null);
    });
  };
});
```

That code works for me, I hope it will work for you as well.

Thanks to let me know !